# Dynamically create x509 certificate in iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, x509

I have an requirement to generate the x509 certificate at run time, I did some google and found few examples to use the certificate instead of creating a certificate.

Thanks & regards,
S. Murali Krishnan

Comment: this certificate is for client side

Comment: For what purpose? It's unlikely to (and shouldn't) be trusted by anything in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to [compile and static link openssl](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/) with your iOS project.

Then create your x509 certificate with the openssl API ([check this example code](https://www.codeblog.org/gonzui/markup/openssl-0.9.8a/demos/x509/mkcert.c))

Comment: I am not suppose to use any 3rd party like openssl.... is there any way to do it with native..... or just tell me how can i send my public key to server in the secure way.

Comment: The public key is public. There's no need to a secure way. So you might send it by HTTP(S) post.